# How to enter newline in refill-mode

Tags: fill-paragraph, auto-fill-mode

If I try to split up a paragraph with `refill-mode` enabled, it fills
immediately after, effectively cancelling out the entered newline.

Say I have this paragraph (with `|` as the cursor):

```
Pellentesque dapibus suscipit ligula. Donec posuere augue in quam. Etiam
vel tortor sodales tellus ultricies commodo. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean
in sem ac leo mollis blandit. Donec neque quam, dignissim in, mollis
nec, sagittis eu, wisi. Phasellus lacus. Etiam laoreet quam sed arcu.
Phasellus at dui in ligula mollis ultricies. |Integer placerat tristique
nisl. Praesent augue. Fusce commodo. Vestibulum convallis, lorem a
tempus semper, dui dui euismod elit, vitae placerat urna tortor vitae
lacus. Nullam libero mauris, consequat quis, varius et, dictum id, arcu.
Mauris mollis tincidunt felis. Aliquam feugiat tellus ut neque. Nulla
facilisis, risus a rhoncus fermentum, tellus tellus lacinia purus, et
dictum nunc justo sit amet elit.
```

I hit `ENT ENT` to get:

```
Pellentesque dapibus suscipit ligula. Donec posuere augue in quam. Etiam
vel tortor sodales tellus ultricies commodo. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean
in sem ac leo mollis blandit. Donec neque quam, dignissim in, mollis
nec, sagittis eu, wisi. Phasellus lacus. Etiam laoreet quam sed arcu.
Phasellus at dui in ligula mollis ultricies.

|Integer placerat tristique nisl. Praesent augue. Fusce commodo.
Vestibulum convallis, lorem a tempus semper, dui dui euismod elit, vitae
placerat urna tortor vitae lacus. Nullam libero mauris, consequat quis,
varius et, dictum id, arcu. Mauris mollis tincidunt felis. Aliquam
feugiat tellus ut neque. Nulla facilisis, risus a rhoncus fermentum,
tellus tellus lacinia purus, et dictum nunc justo sit amet elit.
```

but instead I'm stuck with:

```
Pellentesque dapibus suscipit ligula. Donec posuere augue in quam. Etiam
vel tortor sodales tellus ultricies commodo. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean
in sem ac leo mollis blandit. Donec neque quam, dignissim in, mollis
nec, sagittis eu, wisi. Phasellus lacus. Etiam laoreet quam sed arcu.
Phasellus at dui in ligula mollis ultricies. |Integer placerat tristique
nisl. Praesent augue. Fusce commodo. Vestibulum convallis, lorem a
tempus semper, dui dui euismod elit, vitae placerat urna tortor vitae
lacus. Nullam libero mauris, consequat quis, varius et, dictum id, arcu.
Mauris mollis tincidunt felis. Aliquam feugiat tellus ut neque. Nulla
facilisis, risus a rhoncus fermentum, tellus tellus lacinia purus, et
dictum nunc justo sit amet elit.
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce on my side. Can you confirmed `ENTER` is bound to `newline`?

Comment: Odd, maybe it's a old spacemacs bug. It seems to work on my updated install too. I will check back with my colleague to see if the issue persists.